# How to use an Eclipse Project as a library in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, droidquery

I need to use https://github.com/phil-brown/droidQuery in a new android project. Unfortunately droidquery looks to be an eclipse project and I need to use it as a library in Android Studio. Can this be done?

Comment: You should be able to import it as a module (File > New > Import Module), though it may require some adjustment after being imported.

Comment: Looks like it's in there now, had to modify the build.gradle a bit and now I'm getting some missing package errors but I'm making progress